# Counter number animated if div on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a responsive web page, that uses a simple counter from 0 to a specific number. It is inside a `div class="startAnime"`  and uses a simple JavaScript function to animated. To see this div we have to scroll down. Is it possible that this animation only starts if the div `startAnime` its on screen? No matter how size or how scroll we did in different screens?

Code Animated

```
<script>
$('.count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

html code:

```
<div class="contFacs">

<div id="primary" class="content-area startAnime">

    <div class="col33Fac">
        <p class="itemfact"><?php echo get_field('texto_1'); ?></p>
       <p class="count"> <?php echo get_field('numero_1'); ?></p>
    </div>


    <div class="col33Fac borderDoble">
         <p class="itemfact"><?php echo get_field('texto_2'); ?></p>
         <p class="count"><?php echo get_field('numero_2'); ?></p>

    </div>


    <div class="col33Fac">
        <p class="itemfact"><?php echo get_field('texto_3'); ?></p>
        <p class="count"><?php echo get_field('numero_3'); ?></p>
    </div>


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code correctly in the question when posting. This was barely readable

Comment: can you post the html portion as well